# scrollview leaves extra space at bottom of layout activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

My `Scrollview` leaves space under some `layouts` I'm new to android please, help here is my code:

```
 <ScrollView     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollviewdb"     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
    <LinearLayout    
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:orientation="vertical"    
              android:layout_width="match_parent"    
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
         <TextView        
            android:layout_width="match_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:textSize="15sp"  
            android:padding="5dp"     
            android:id="@+id/ghavaed_text"/> 
      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: add screenshot..so people can help you..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use  android:fillViewport="true" in scrollview

Comment: it didnt work for me I tried it before @PradeepGupta

Answer (score 6):

Add `android:fillViewport` in your ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollviewdb"     
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
    <LinearLayout    
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:orientation="vertical"    
      android:layout_width="match_parent"    
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
         <TextView        
            android:layout_width="match_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
            android:textSize="15sp"  
            android:padding="5dp"     
            android:id="@+id/ghavaed_text"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As @Ironman explained, The reason behind this is ScrollView would become useless if its content was always as tall as itself. To work around this, you need to use the ScrollView attribute called `android:fillViewport`. When set to true, this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed. When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect

Comment: I give +1 to you because your answer is correct but you have to add explaination that `ScrollView would become useless if its content was always as tall as itself. To work around this, you need to use the ScrollView attribute called android:fillViewport. When set to true, this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed. When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect`

Comment: it doesnt get solved with fillViewport :( @MahfuzIslamBhuiyan

Comment: @Erik_DA add the screenShot please.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and solved it by adding :`android:layout_gravity="top"` to the  `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add marginBottoom with minus value on scrollview.

Also in my case, I found that the background height takes more space on the bottom.
solution: I have moved the background from the relative layout to the scroll view and it has been solved this problem.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/bg" //i move this background here from realative 
    layout
android:overScrollMode="never"
>
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

In Scroll view use `android:fillViewport` attribute to set scrollview  height and width fill port (Match parent) . if we are not use this attribute in scroll view ,its behave as a wrap_content

**Code:**

```
 <ScrollView     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/scrollviewdb"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:fillViewport="true" >  
<LinearLayout    
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:orientation="vertical"    
          android:layout_width="match_parent"    
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
     <TextView        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:textSize="15sp"  
        android:padding="5dp"     
        android:id="@+id/ghavaed_text"/> 
  </LinearLayout>
```